# How to configure the More menu on the tab bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

i have programmatically  created a tab bar and added 7 view controllers to it as tabs , since i have added 7 , i got a more button (i know that it ill come if tabs r more than 5) in the more menu, there is a edit button on the navigation bar on the right , on click of that edit button it navigated to the '[image: Configure]' screen , my question is what is the use of this screen,,what can be done here? can we do repositioning of tabs? if so how can we do? i have searched for long time but didn't get any solution,,,thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can reposition tabs. Just drag the icon you want down to the UITabBar and it will replace for the icon you drop over.

Comment: Ya after a long try i got to know that,,thanx for ur reply